# c++: STL uses universal "end()" value for iterator?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

Does the ".end()" iterator for all instances of a given STL container point to the same "past-the-end" object?

e.g.

```
std::set<int> my_set_1;
// fill  "my_set_1"
std::set<int> my_set_2;
// fill  "my_set_2"

bool same_end_iterator  =       my_set_1.end() == my_set_2.end()    ;
```

Is the last line implementation-dependent?

Answer (score 10):

> Does the ".end()" iterator for all instances of a given STL container point to the same "past-the-end" object?

No, the standard gives no guarantee of that, and in practice some container types probably won't work like that. For example `std::vector::iterator` is typically implemented as a pointer to an array element, with `end()` pointing past the end of the array.

> Is the last line implementation-dependent?

The last line gives undefined behaviour. You can't compare iterators from different collections - including past-the-end iterators.

Comment: But my question was specifically about the ".end()"  iterator.  So your answer basically is:  "No, because it is not true", which is useless.

Comment: @CycoMatto: Mike's answer covers the general case, from which the `end()` case follows immediately.

Comment: @CycoMatto: Sorry if my answer was too brief for you. I've fleshed it out a bit to specifically answer your question.

Answer (score 4):

Conceptually, there's one off-the-end iterator *per container* and comparing iterators into different containers, even those of the same type, is UB.

In fact, for old school arrays, the off-the-end iterator is `a+N` where `a` is the base of the array and `N` is the number of elements in it, which means different off-the-end iterators for different arrays. This is also the most sensible implementation for `std::vector::iterator` that I can think of.

Comment: That is the correct concept for "old-school arrays", but not necessarily the case for STL containers.  While it may be attractive to our intuition to use  "past-the-end" metaphor, there is  no indication that this is reality for STL containers (espeically outside of `vector`.)

Comment: @CycoMatto: I addressed the general case in my first sentence. There's one off-the-end iterator per container; an implementation may choose to use the same value for all containers of a certain type, but you can't rely on that.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowlegde, comparisons of iterators belonging to different containers is undefined, I don't recall which. This rather implies that given `std::vector<int> foo, bar`, `foo.end()` is not the same as `bar.end()`.